# RGB to fill color in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task to generate a color code . I have the R G B values listed in three different columns and there are around 256 rows of R G B values. I need to fill the color corresponding to the R G B values in each row.

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDGFu.jpg)

This is how it has been listed . And i would require to generate the corresponding color code next to this

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ChangeRowColorBasedonAtoCRGBValues()
Dim lRw As Long

lRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lRw
    Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = _
        RGB(Cells(i, "A").Value, Cells(i, "B").Value, Cells(i, "C").Value)
Next i

End Sub
```